# Why isn't my glfw window showing anything?

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, glfw

I have been working with GLFW but recently encountered a weired problem,

I have the following code which was designed to draw a colored cube inside a glfw window. But the screen simply is blank, no error given. Here is a minimum reproducible code in Python:

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np
from OpenGL import GL as gl
from OpenGL.GL import shaders


def load_shaders(vertex_shader, fragment_shader):
    vertex_shader = open(vertex_shader, "r").read()
    fragment_shader = open(fragment_shader, "r").read()
    active_shader = shaders.compileProgram(
        shaders.compileShader(vertex_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
        shaders.compileShader(fragment_shader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER),
    )
    return active_shader


if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized!")


glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, glfw.TRUE)
glfw.window_hint(glfw.OPENGL_PROFILE, glfw.OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE)
window = glfw.create_window(640, 480, "glfw test", None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)

gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glfw.swap_interval(1)
l = -0.5
h = 0.5
verts = np.array([
    l, l, h,  h, l, h,  l, h, h,  h, h, h,  # FRONT
    l, l, l,  l, h, l,  h, l, l,  h, h, l,  # BACK
    l, l, h,  l, h, h,  l, l, l,  l, h, l,  # LEFT
    h, l, l,  h, h, l,  h, l, h,  h, h, h,  # RIGHT
    l, h, h,  h, h, h,  l, h, l,  h, h, l,  # TOP
    l, l, h,  l, l, l,  h, l, h,  h, l, l   # BOTTOM
], dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1, 3)

colors = np.array([
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
], dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1, 3)

vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
glBindVertexArray(vao)
shader = load_shaders(
    "shaders/copy_vert.glsl", "shaders/copy_frag.glsl")

pos = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pos)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verts.nbytes, verts.reshape(-1), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, verts.shape[-1], GL_FLOAT, False, 0, 0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

frag = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, frag)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colors.nbytes,
             colors.reshape(-1), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, colors.shape[-1], GL_FLOAT, False, 0, 0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glUseProgram(shader)
    glBindVertexArray(vao)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 24)

    glUseProgram(0)
    glBindVertexArray(0)
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1)

    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    glfw.poll_events()
glfw.destroy_window(window)
glfw.terminate()
```

Here are my shaders:

```
#version 330 core
out vec3 color;
void main(){
  color = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
```

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){    
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(pos, 1.0);
}
```

The thing is, if I change `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` to `GL_POINTS` I can see a bright point in the origin of the window, which clearly is a sign of not having any data in the buffer. But I am pretty sure my buffers are fine?

I am using `glfw==2.7.0` and `PyOpenGL==3.1.7`. The program is tested on a M1 mac and a linux mahcine with Ubuntu22.04, but the result is the same. Am I mssing something here?

if I use this code, the drawing is fine, I can see the red side of the cube facing me:

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np
from OpenGL import GL as gl
from OpenGL.GL import shaders


def load_shaders(vertex_shader, fragment_shader):
    vertex_shader = open(vertex_shader, "r").read()
    fragment_shader = open(fragment_shader, "r").read()
    active_shader = shaders.compileProgram(
        shaders.compileShader(vertex_shader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
        shaders.compileShader(fragment_shader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER),
    )
    return active_shader


if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized!")


window = glfw.create_window(640, 480, "glfw test", None, None)
glfw.make_context_current(window)

gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glfw.swap_interval(1)
l = -0.5
h = 0.5
verts = np.array([
    l, l, h,  h, l, h,  l, h, h,  h, h, h,  # FRONT
    l, l, l,  l, h, l,  h, l, l,  h, h, l,  # BACK
    l, l, h,  l, h, h,  l, l, l,  l, h, l,  # LEFT
    h, l, l,  h, h, l,  h, l, h,  h, h, h,  # RIGHT
    l, h, h,  h, h, h,  l, h, l,  h, h, l,  # TOP
    l, l, h,  l, l, l,  h, l, h,  h, l, l   # BOTTOM
], dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1, 3)

colors = np.array([
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
], dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1, 3)


while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts)
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4)

    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4)

    glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4)

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    glfw.poll_events()
glfw.destroy_window(window)
glfw.terminate()
```

Unfortunately, this is not what I want. Not using glsl is painful.

Comment: `MVP` is not set.

Comment: sorry, wrong shader pasted, this is the one I'm actually using:
`
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;

out vec3 frag;

void main(){ 
 gl_Position =  vec4(pos, 1.0);
 frag = color;
}
`
`
#version 330 core

in vec3 frag;
out vec4 color_out;
void main(){
  color_out = vec4(frag, 1.0);
}
`

Comment: @Rabbid76 The problem is still here tho, regardless of setting MVP or not

Answer (score -1):

Simply changing;

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, verts.shape[-1], GL_FLOAT, False, 0, 0)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, colors.shape[-1], GL_FLOAT, False, 0, 0)
```

to:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, verts.shape[-1], GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, colors.shape[-1], GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
```

solved the problem for me.

Comment: @BDL yes, colors should be location 1. my bad.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).